# Replace a string with a word basing on nth occurence using php

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have a string with anchor tags i filtered the string and got all anchor tags and value.

my array will be :

```
Array 
(
  [www.google.com] = Array 
      (
        [0]=> click here
        [1]=> search engine
      }
  [http://www.gmail.com] => Array
    (
     [0] => text1
     [1] => 
     [2] => text2
     [3] => 
    )
)
```

Now i want to replace the link basing on occurrence. Here 0,1,2 .. represents occurrence of
a string. What should i do if i want to replace 3rd occurrence of gmail link.

How to replace a string basing on its occurrence? Can anyone help me out of this ?

Comment: So it seems like you are scanning a full html page and capturing anchor tags via function like `preg_match_all`? Does the replacement has to be always 3rd time? What's your aim here?

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding it seems like this would work:

```
foreach(array_keys($array_of_anchors) as $anchor_text) {
    if(count($array_of_anchors[$anchor_text]) > 2) {
        $array_of_anchors[$anchor_text][2] = //do replace   
    }
}
```

A simple loop to search through each anchor, see if there are more than 2 occurrences and then do whatever you want with the 2 index (3rd occurrence) in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear, but if you only want to replace the **x**th occurrence of a string you can replace all `x` occurrences then undo `x - 1`. Assuming `$target` is your string, `$search` is what you're looking for, and `$replace` is the replacement then you could try:

```
str_replace($search, $replace, $target, $x); 
str_replace($replace, $search, $target, ($x - 1));
```

But, be careful, this will go wrong if there was an occurrence of the `$replace` string already in `$target`. To be really safe you should check for `$replace` first. This also works for `preg_replace`.

Alternatively you could do `preg_match` in a loop, counting the matches and moving the offset forward through the string. Then when the count matches what you want do `preg_replace` to replace that one.

If you're working with HTML it might be better to try and parse as a structured document rather than using search/replace.

Comment: Sorry for my bad explanation. You understood my question in right manner. Thank you. But i need to replace the string basing on occurrence not just the last one and no other string with same $search word much not disturb if its index(occurrence) value is not matched.

Comment: OK. Can you share the regular expression you're using to get the initial array and an example of what you want to change the text to (several if you want to change the replacement each time)? It's possible you can just use `preg_replace` repeatedly to replace each occurrence -- but I can't really tell without a better example.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution for my problem instead replacing all search words at once using offset position. Its better to replace one after the other in sequential manner which helps in resolving the problem.

```
protected  function replaceLinkWithShortUrl($content,$toReplace,$search){
        $pos = strpos($content,$search);
        $replacedContent = substr_replace($content, $toReplace, $pos).substr($content, $pos+strlen($search));
        return $replacedContent;
    }
```

Above code will search for a word in content and replace with a value and append the content again. This procedure will repeat untill replacing all search key's with values.

Thank you guys for those who helped me in resolving the problem. Thank you SpaceDog..